# Ethers Provider CORS error with JsonRPCProvider inside of react application

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

Having an issue where my ethers provider is giving me a cors issue for just read only functions. I am not even creating any transactions or anything. I have tried changing nodes and different rpcs but it doesn't help. Archive node, standard bsc rpc, moralis, tried it all. You can find an image of the errors I get below. Heres my provider code which I import to all the function pages and heres an example of a function below that. Very basic stuff.

This is a basic react application that is displaying some information about a Binance smart chain token.

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/1c2baaae7c0d11120337ddc1/bsc/mainnet"
);

export default provider;
```

Example function:

```
export const getReflectionLive = async () => {
  try {
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, tokenAbi, provider);

    let rate = await getDeadRate();
    
    tokenContract.on("Transfer", async (from, to, value, event2) => {
      console.log("New Dead Balance addition", (value / 10 ** 9) * 0.05 * rate);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error --> ${error}`);
  }
};
```

[image: All My Error Codes]

Comment: Any info on how you fixed it, if fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to move this to server side and have the client call the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own proxy and use it with the provider

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
```